# JOOMLA + XML Parsing Error at 1:1496. Error 4: not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: xml, joomla, parsing, joomla1.5, token

I am receiving the error: "XML Parsing Error at 1:1496. Error 4: not well-formed (invalid token)" on all pages of a Joomla install. Not sure exactly when the error started but it was working before. I have recently installed SOBI2 and 4RSS components, however when I disable or uninstall them the error still shows up.

**Joomla Version 1.5.15**

URL: **http://magni.webcity.com.au/~bes47125/water-alerts/**

Any help with solving this error or even removing the display of it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Has your host recently upgraded to a new PHP?

Are you using rokweather? http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=615&p=2861177

Answer (score 0):

This can happen for a variety of reasons, but all point back to an XML file being invalid. Some common causes:

- a file you have uploaded was uploaded corruptly
- a component/module/etc you are using has a bad XML file
- there's some mischief going on...

It can be a little tricky to figure out exactly which file (the error message only shows line/column!), so I find it handy to go into the administration area. From there, go to 'Extensions' -> 'Install/Uninstall'.

Now click through the 'Components', 'Modules', 'Plugins', 'Languages', 'Templates' tabs. Note that the error could be in an XML file for any of these - and if you're noticing it on every page, then I would suspect a Language or Template is most likely.

If the same error comes up when you go to a tab, then one of the items in that tab has an invalid XML file. From there I'd try checking the files on your site vs. known good copies (filesize can be a good indication), and re-upload any corrupted files.